# SQLAlchemy not updating changes causing issues

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, alembic

So I've made some changes to my schema on a Flask Server, using SQLite and SQLAlchemy. The database is generally functional and I'm able to add some of the models, as well as update and query all models without issues.

I've changed the `id` in two of my models from Integer to String in order to implement uuid ids, and since I've received `IntegrityError` for the mismatching parameter types when I do `db.session.add(new_post)` and `db.session.commit()`.

If I do `flask db migrate`, it reports that no changes have been detected. Should I manually fill out a revision file or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to migrating your database, you'll need to upgrade:

```
flask db upgrade
```

If this results in an error, you might be encountering database specific constraints. For example, some primary keys cannot be removed without setting cascade rules on deletion for relationships.